# Command yum error: -bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, python, centos-7

I can't use command "yum" on centos 7, when I try to install packet software there is a description

> -bash: / usr / bin / yum: / usr / bin / python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Please share the exact command you're running and share the output of `type yum`, if any.